# disable checkbox based on a parameter in mvc2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

In my Page I am using following code to disable and enable   a check box based on a value

```
<% var customfieldStatus="";
                 if(Model.customFieldsList.Count()<1)
                 {
                     customfieldStatus = "DISABLED =\"DISABLED\"";
                 } %>
                    <%= Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.enableCustomFields, new {  customfieldStatus  })%><a href="#"><%:(VoxMVC.App_GlobalResources.Label.Search_CustomFields)%></a></li>
```

But  the check box is always enabled.i can see that

customfieldStatus = "DISABLED =\"DISABLED\"";

But its not disabling the check box

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot instantiate an anonymous object in this way.  You are parsing in a single String value.  Try this instead:

```
<% 
  object customParams = null;
  if(Model.customFieldsList.Count() < 1)
  {
    customParams = new { disabled = "disabled" };
  } 
%>
<%= Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.enableCustomFields, customParams) %>
```